# Where can I get the full set of Shadal's commentary on the Torah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, jewish-books, commentaries, shadal

I'm a big fan of Shadal's commentary on the Torah, but I can't find anyone selling the full set.  There's an english translation of Breishis only and the full hebrew version is available online, but I want a Shabbos-friendly version of the complete set.

Comment: Print it out? [15]

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance. Shadal was orthodox?

Comment: @kouty. You're forgiven. Why do you ask?

Comment: @ShimonbM I am Am haarets Gamur in mefarshe haHumash. I know RMH Luzzato, but not SD, and it is strange that I never heard. So perhaps this commentary is not known. I love Italian rabanim.

Comment: Actually, *Rabbi* SD. Here is his rabbinic ordination:
http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2012/11/shadal-series-14-on-shadals-unusual.html

Comment: @kouty here is the wiki article on him https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_David_Luzzatto I guess you can decide for yourself which of his views and and practices would qualify to call him Orthodox or not.

Comment: @user6591  A whole world. In Italy the separation between jewish groups was not as today.

Comment: @kouty that's exactly why I said decide for yourself. And everyone else can decide for themselves.

Comment: https://kodeshpress.com/product/shadal-exodus-hc

Comment: FTR, the original editions (five volumes) had an Italian transl. of the Pentateuch together with Shadal’s commentary. Later (and contemporary) editions only published the commentary.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [Shadal - Torah Commentary by Samuel David Luzzatto(4vol)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9655240673), translated and annotated by Eliyahu Munk.

Comment: see though this review. he uses the censored version, and makes (imho) some questionable interpretations of Shadal. http://parsha.blogspot.com/2012/10/review-of-new-translation-of-shadals.html

Answer (score 1):

A full Shabbos-friendly Hebrew set is available [here](http://www.carmelph.co.il/extensions/virtuemart/detail/17-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/youbooks/1238-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%A9%D7%93-%D7%9C-%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%A8%D7%A9-%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA?sef=hcfp).  This is the full version of his commentary, not censored, although it is lacking in notes (as I gather from Daniel Klein's introduction to his [English translation of Shemot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0692522069)).