# Looking for Shadal Al HaTorah

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, internet, acharonim, shadal

I am looking for Shadal's commentary on the Torah. is it available for free online?
If not does anyone know where it can be purchased the cheapest?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15484/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shadal has two commentaries on Torah:

- a shorter one called Mishtadel
- a longer one, with two printings. One of these printings is a censored text, which leaves out e.g. some of Shadal's citations of gentile scholars. This one is available online in plain text. The other of these printings is the full uncensored version and is available on Google Books (but might then only be accessible if you are in the United States).
- there is also Ohev Ger, which is Shadal's supercommentary on Targum Onkelos, where he tries to establish the correct text.

On parshablog, I have, parsha by parsha, links to a variety of meforshim. For example, here is [Bereishit Sources](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2012/10/bereishit-sources-2012-edition.html). For Bereishit:

- [Mishtadel](http://books.google.com/books?id=2q9WAAAAMAAJ&dq=%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9&lr&as_brr=3&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- [Censored full commentary in plain text](http://www.tora.us.fm/tnk1/jdl/MefarsheyTanach001-01.htm) (modify the url to get each perek. By this I mean that the url is http://www.tora.us.fm/tnk1/jdl/MefarsheyTanach001-01.htm and to get to Bereishit perek 2 change it to 001-02.htm, and to get to Shemot perek 1 change it to 002-01.htm)
- [Uncensored full commentary](http://books.google.com/books?id=k30tAAAAYAAJ&as_brr=1&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=&f=false), along with Shadal's translation of pesukim to Italian.
- [Ohev Ger](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20619&st=&pgnum=41&hilite=)

I will give links here to the full commentary for the other four Chumashim. For the rest, you can modify the url yourself, or scroll in the book, or else search parshablog for the Source Roundup for that particular parasha.

Uncensored full commentary for:

1. [Bereishit](http://books.google.com/books?id=k30tAAAAYAAJ&as_brr=1&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
2. [Shemot](http://books.google.com/books?id=RZItAAAAYAAJ&dq=inauthor%3A%22Samuel%20David%20Luzzatto%22%20%E1%B8%A4amishah%20%E1%B8%A5umshe%20Torah&as_brr=1&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
3. [Vayikra](http://books.google.com/books?id=UnwpAAAAYAAJ&as_brr=1&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
4. [Bemidbar](http://books.google.com/books?id=2X4tAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:0Xsqzch6wYCUUn&as_brr=1#PPA2,M1)
5. [Devarim](http://books.google.com/books?id=v5MtAAAAYAAJ&as_brr=1&pg=PP12)

Comment: does mishtadel exist on the whole Torah?  If so where do I find it?  Does mishtadel ever have any info. not found in the long commentary?

Comment: yes. it is all at that link above, in a single sefer. however, the sefer was scanned backwards. so, to get to sefer Shemot, for instance, you need to scroll UP, rather than down. Mishtadel is shorter but iirc sometimes contains  different explanations.

Comment: @mevaqesh 1. Yes. 2. Best bet is prob. at second-hand bookstores. 3. Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Sefaria has some of his writings.

[Bereishis](http://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Genesis)

[Shemos](http://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Exodus)

[Vayikra](http://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Leviticus)

[Bamidbar](http://www.sefaria.org/Shadal_on_Numbers)

Comment: I wrote "some" under the assumption that he wrote on Devarim.  I don't know so much about Shadal other than that I generally see him being quoted by less mainstream sources.

Comment: yez, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12646/759

Answer (score 1):

http://ishimshitos.blogspot.com/2008/09/blog-post.html?m=1

This may be your best bet. Not all the links seem to be working, but the Torah ones are.